# Primefaces schedule daylight-saving time

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PF 4.0, I ve made simple day and hour picker based on schedule. The problem is that I dont know how to handle with daylight-saving time. I mean at summer i had problem that when I were picking hour at schedule, the time were -1 than smth i ve picked. I seted  timeZone="GMT+2" and it worked fine, but now we got winter and it works when I delete timeZone ...

Answer (score -1):

I don't know I understand your problem but make sure you have configure

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in your web.xml

Comment: please tell me about JDK version for this projct And 
Please check this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html

Comment: java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)